# Is it possible to enable CORS for only my Android APP

Tags: php, android, cordova, cors

Im working on a android app, with cordova. In some point of the app, I have to call a PHP script. *(Yes, it has to be in PHP because there is no big chance to do it differntly. Please don't focus on that point, to exclude PHP from my app.)*

My few hours researches regarding integrate PHP into cordova shows me that this is not directly possible.

This is why, I was thinking to host my PHP files on my personal domain, which is able to run PHP scripts.

Always when I call the PHP from my domain trough my Android App, it fails:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/php/todo.php' from
>   origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I know that I could disable CORS policy on my domain - so it would be able to run it. But then there would be a security risk in genearl.

**But my question is:**

Can I allow only CORS CALL from my app, and disallow from everything other?

Or do you have some idea how to solve it?

Comment: You should be able to add the header from within your php script.

Comment: @user9189147 Sorry, but what do you mean? Could you please expain it more in detail? Thank you.

Comment: You should at least add the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to your PHP response using the PHP header() function. This would allow anyone to have cross domain access to your PHP server. Since your app sends the header `Origin: http://localhost` it would be useless to do further origin checks on the server. That should be fixed first.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I allow only CORS CALL from my app, and disallow from everything
>   other?

No you can't. CORS only protects the clients from cross origin attacks, but not the servers. Everyone can forge a request that your server would happily accept. You would need to use something like an API-Key to protect your servers from unwanted access.